# In Numbers.app, how can I trigger a response if newly input cell text matches text found anywhere in other sheets?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-synchronization, numbers, csv

In Numbers.app on iOS, is it possible to trigger a response if sheet contains differing data to other sheets in same file? If not able to formulate on iOS, then on a Mac? And will the trigger still show up when viewing same file on iOS?

- Sheet 1 = contact list from phone A
- Sheet 2 = contact list from phone B
- Sheet 3 = message list from phone C
- Sheet 4 = contact list from phone

`contact name for phone 123-456-7890`

- Sheet 1 = *contact doesn’t exist*
- Sheet 2 = Jane Doe
- Sheet 3 = Jane Doe
- Sheet 4 = Ashley

How can I set a trigger that will alert me to Sheet 4’s cell “Ashley”?

Each sheet contains different

- number of rows
- column headers

Answer (score 0):

No, this sort of processing every single input and making a list to scan would progressively slow down the app each and every cell that fills.

The problem you’re trying to solve os better suited for a relational database with indexes and stored procedures to map and search as opposed to using a spreadsheet for a database.

Are you mostly doing lookups and not data entry here?